# Создание обработчика событий динамически созданных компонентов ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net, c#

У меня есть массив, состоящий из LinkButton. Нужно для каждого элемента массива создавать свой обработчик.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton[] button = new LinkButton[10];
    int i = 0;
    Query query = new Query();
    SqlDataReader myReader = query.ExecuteQuery("select * from myusers");
    while (myReader.Read()) 
    {
        if (i < 10)
        {
            LinkButton newbutton = new LinkButton();
            newbutton.ID = "but" + i;
            button[i] = newbutton;
            query.ExecuteQuery("select ic, name, surname from myusers");
            button[i].Text = Convert.ToString(myReader["name"]) +" "+ Convert.ToString(myReader["surname"]);
            button[i].OnClientClick += new EventHandler(this.link_Click);                 
            form1.Controls.Add(button[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }

}

protected void link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton link = (LinkButton)sender;
    Session["name"] = link.Text;          
}
```

Но обработка события не происходит. Помогите! В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Зачем button[i] = newbutton?

Работайте с newbutton, он у Вас всё равно каждый раз новый, а потом его добавляйте в массив.

А вообще лучше всё через шаблон и Repeater как у меня ниже.

Comment: По моему так:

LinkButton newbutton = new LinkButton();

newbutton.ID = "but" + i;

query.ExecuteQuery("select ic, name, surname from myusers");

newbutton.Text = Convert.ToString(myReader["name"]) + " " + Convert.ToString(myReader["surname"]);

newbutton.OnClientClick += new EventHandler(this.link_Click);

button[i] = newbutton;

form1.Controls.Add(button[i]);

i++;

Comment: Млин сразу не заменил, всё правильно у Вас не работает. Событие клиентское, а обработчик серверный.

Вот так попробуйте:

newbutton.Click += new EventHandler(this.link_Click);

Comment: огромное спасибо! все теперь работает!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Публикую более подробный код, раз не совсем понятно:

Форма:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="RolesGrid" allowpaging="true" 
autogeneratecolumns="False" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0"
pagesize="7" width="100%" UseAccessibleHeader="true">

<Columns>
    <asp:templateField runat="server" headerText="Имя роли" >
        <itemTemplate>
            <%# Container.DataItem %>
        </itemTemplate>
    </asp:templateField>

    <asp:templateField runat="server" >
        <itemStyle horizontalAlign="center"/>
        <itemTemplate>
            <asp:linkButton runat="server" id="linkButton2" text="Удалить"
            commandArgument='<%#Container.DataItem%>' OnCommand='DelRoleClick'
            OnClientClick="if (confirm('Вы уверены, что хотите удалить эту запись?') == false) return false;" />
        </itemTemplate>
    </asp:templateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Сервер:

```
//Удаляем роль
       public void DelRoleClick(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            string rolename = (string)e.CommandArgument;
            if(Roles.RoleExists(rolename))
                Roles.DeleteRole(rolename);
            BindRoles();
        }

//Обновляем список ролей. При первой загрузке эта функция также вызывается, чтобы инициализировать список    
        public void BindRoles()
        {
            string[] arr = Roles.GetAllRoles();
            RolesGrid.DataSource = arr;
            RolesGrid.DataBind();
        }
```

Вот еще вариант с Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptAlphabet" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptAlphabet_ItemCommand">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem %>' runat="server"><%# Container.DataItem %></asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Заполняем список, при загрузке:

```
string[] alphabet = "a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l;m;n;o;p;q;r;s;t;u;v;w;x;y;z;все".Split(';');
rptAlphabet.DataSource = alphabet;
rptAlphabet.DataBind();
```

Обрабатываем нажатие:

```
protected void rptAlphabet_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandArgument.ToString().Length == 1){
            gvwUsers.Attributes.Add("SearchText", e.CommandArgument.ToString() + "%");
            BindUsers(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: так у меня массив из LinkButton, они создаются динамически в зависимомти, сколько у меня данных, поэтому обработчик нужно писать программно...

Comment: У меня тоже динамически, а кто мешает шаблон использовать?

Дополнил ответ, чтобы было понятнее. Если есть еще вопросы, буду рад помочь.

Comment: Ну, или дайте свой код, на месте подправим его.

Comment: Добавил вариант с репиатером, см. выше.

Comment: посмотрите мой код выше!

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, это связано с тем, что отрабатывает обработчик кнопки в другом экземпляре формы по отношению к тому, в котором он создавался.

- Пользователь открыл Web-форму.
- Вызвался обработчик Page_Load, создались кнопки.
- Форма вместе с кнопками отрендерилась и уничтожилась.
- Пользователь нажал на кнопку
- Происходит PostBasck
- На сервере создаётся новый экземпляр Web-формы
- В Page_Load снова создались кнопки, но это новые кнопки, а не те, события которых надо обработать.

Ещё не совсем понятно, почему Вы подписываетесь на OnClientClick, а не на OnClick.

Comment: что в таком случае мне нужно исправить??

Comment: Я бы поместил ссылку на Repeater и обработчик для неё задал в aspx-файле через атрибут.

Comment: Можете написать пример кода, если не трудно!!

Answer (score 1):

Потому что OnClick недоступен. OnClientClick для обработки на клиенте, и он ну никак не вызовет событие на сервере. Это заведомо неверный путь!

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?